# Using a UIGestureRecognizer in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Previously I've used the tap Detecting Window technique to detect taps in a UIWebView, but now I've tried to use gesture recognizers instead. The following code is in the viewDidLoad method of a view controller, which has a single UIWebView.  This code compiles fine, but the handleTap method is never called. This seems like it should be simple.

```
// Configure a gesture recognizer to detect taps in the web view
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap)];
[self.myWebView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];    
[singleTap release];

[super viewDidLoad];
```

Answer (score 6):

Set your view controller as the recognizer delegate:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap)];
recognizer.delegate = self;
[self.myWebView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

And enable simultaneous gesture recognition (as the UIWebView probably sets a few recognizers itself, yours are skipped) :

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This worked well for me. You can also add conditions inside `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` to isolate the gesture classes you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `UIWebView` does already handle a lot of touch events, it might be a bit tricky to add your own gesture recognizer.

I don't know if the user has to interact with your web view but you might try to add a `UIView` on top of the `UIWebView` and add the gesture recognizer to this view. It should still propagate unrecognized touch events to the underlying web view, thus leaving its interactivity intact.